# Wifi connection access using an android app

Tags: android, networking, network-programming, wifi, android-wifi

I want to develop an android app which will be use to connect an specific wifi network. This wifi network will have no password security. Anyone can connect with this network because there is no password security but they will not get any internet connection only those people who have my app install in there mobile only they will get the internet connection.

I don't know how to start. If anyone can help me or can give me any reference that will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If its open wifi connection, i donot think you can control it unless you go with specific router like microtik which has radius server etc..

Answer (score 1):

the only solution i can think of is you develop a app login to a firewall , and if you use this for a limited user this app can send phone mac address to another desktop app that write them to your modem-router